# Php checkbox retrieve data from database

Tags: php, checkbox

I have:

```
$array_worker['$worker_id']=$worker_name;  
$array_job['$job_id']=$job_name;
```

I have no problem with dynamic create table with checkbox and store data in database:

The data are stored in table as worker_id,job_id!
Normally, worker may work more than one job, so I create multidimensional array from table in which the stored data!

```
$array_worded['$worker_id'][]=$job_id;
```

My question is:

How create dynamic table with **checked** checkboxes based on **array_worked** array?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Also, no one here will write code for you.

Comment: array_worked?????????????????

Comment: @asprin: worker, please don't patronize over obvious typos.

Comment: It might have been over obvious to you, but it didn't struck me that it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table='';

  foreach($array_worker as $key=>$value){
    $table.=''.$value.''; // worker name
      $worker_id = // get worker id from $array_worker

      foreach($array_job as $key_job=>$val_job)
      {
        $job_id = // get job id from $array_job 

        $checked = false;
        foreach( $array_worked[$worker_id] as $key_worked => $val_worked )
        {
          if( $job_id == $val_worked ) // $val_worked contains $job_id
          {
            $checked = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        $table.='<input type="checkbox"' . ( $checked ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '/>'.$val_job.''; // all jobs from database    
      }
    $table.='';           
  }
$table.='';
```

I may make some mistakes in syntax, but code demonstrates basic principle.

Comment: Thanks **doktorgradus**, it works perfectly! The only thing I do not understand is line 12 where joining variable **$worker_id** to **$array_worked**! Can you explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: Which line is twelve? `foreach( $array_worked[$worker_id] as $key_worked => $val_worked )` - this?

Comment: Yes, that line! I do not understand why is variable **$worker_id** assign to $array_worked? Many thanks!

Comment: Because `$array_worded['$worker_id'][]=$job_id;`. $array_worded => $array_worked, right? In first cell ['$worker_id'] you keep $worker_id. In `foreach` loop at line 12 we get not all array, but only job_ids for current $worker_id.

Comment: And remove commas: `$array_worker['$worker_id']=$worker_name;`, `$array_job['$job_id']=$job_name;`,`$array_worded['$worker_id'][]=$job_id;` => `$array_worker[$worker_id]=$worker_name;`, `$array_job[$job_id]=$job_name;`,`$array_worked[$worker_id][]=$job_id;` see here output: http://codepad.org/43EqSENr

Comment: Thank you for everything! Now I can see where I screwed up, once again, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="formWheelchair"  
<?php
$DATABASE-VALUE = $array_worded['$worker_id'][] = $job_id; // OR WHAT EVER
switch ($DATABASE-VALUE) {
    case 0:
        echo checked />"
        break;
........
}
?>
```